# How to turn off logging for a Google Cloud storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to follow the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/logging to turn off logging for a bucket, `www.peek.solutions`. Here is how the bucket looks in my Google Cloud Console:

[image]

As you can see, the name of the bucket is `www.peek.solutions`. So I tried the following command:

```
gsutil logging set off -b gs://www.peek.solutions
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
CommandException: No URLs matched: []
```

Yet the `gsutil ls` command does show that bucket:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:~ kurtpeek$ gsutil ls
gs://www.peek.solutions/
```

(The `ls` command shows it with a trailing slash, but if I add that it still doesn't work).

Is there something wrong my syntax or understanding of the documentation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that the command works [without the `-b` option](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/logging):

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:~ kurtpeek$ gsutil logging set off gs://www.peek.solutions
Disabling logging on gs://www.peek.solutions/...
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting your own answer? For future reference of the community.